# Kubeflow sdk - error in client.list_experiments()

Tags: kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines, kfp

I'm following the example in docs (https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/sdk/connect-api/) but am getting an error when trying to access the experiments or runs (when trying to list and/or create them)

I've port-forwarded ml-pipeline-ui:

```
kubectl port-forward svc/ml-pipeline-ui 3000:80 --namespace kubeflow
```

The following results in an error:

```
import kfp
client = kfp.Client(host='http://localhost:3000')
print(client.list_experiments())
```

The error I get from `client.list_experiments()`:

```
> ApiException: (500) Reason: Internal Server Error HTTP response
> headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'X-Powered-By': 'Express', 'content-type':
> 'application/json', 'trailer': 'Grpc-Trailer-Content-Type', 'date':
> 'Thu, 22 Jul 2021 21:09:12 GMT', 'x-envoy-upstream-service-time': '7',
> 'server': 'envoy', 'connection': 'close', 'transfer-encoding':
> 'chunked'}) HTTP response body: {"error":"Internal error:
> Unauthenticated: Request header error: there is no user identity
> header.: Request header error: there is no user identity
> header.\nFailed to authorize with API resource
> references\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/common/util.Wrap\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/common/util/error.go:275\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server.(*ExperimentServer).canAccessExperiment\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server/experiment_server.go:249\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server.(*ExperimentServer).ListExperiment\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server/experiment_server.go:148\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client._ExperimentService_ListExperiment_Handler.func1\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client/experiment.pb.go:748\nmain.apiServerInterceptor\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/interceptor.go:30\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client._ExperimentService_ListExperiment_Handler\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client/experiment.pb.go:750\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).processUnaryRPC\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.34.0/server.go:1210\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.34.0/server.go:1533\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1.2\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.34.0/server.go:871\nruntime.goexit\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1357\nFailed
> to authorize with API resource
> references\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/common/util.Wrap\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/common/util/error.go:275\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server.(*ExperimentServer).ListExperiment\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server/experiment_server.go:150\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client._ExperimentService_ListExperiment_Handler.func1\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client/experiment.pb.go:748\nmain.apiServerInterceptor\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/interceptor.go:30\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client._ExperimentService_ListExperiment_Handler\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client/experiment.pb.go:750\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).processUnaryRPC\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.34.0/server.go:1210\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.34.0/server.go:1533\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1.2\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.34.0/server.go:871\nruntime.goexit\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1357","code":13,"message":"Internal
> error: Unauthenticated: Request header error: there is no user
> identity header.: Request header error: there is no user identity
> header.\nFailed to authorize with API resource
> references\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/common/util.Wrap\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/common/util/error.go:275\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server.(*ExperimentServer).canAccessExperiment\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server/experiment_server.go:249\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server.(*ExperimentServer).ListExperiment\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server/experiment_server.go:148\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client._ExperimentService_ListExperiment_Handler.func1\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client/experiment.pb.go:748\nmain.apiServerInterceptor\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/interceptor.go:30\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client._ExperimentService_ListExperiment_Handler\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client/experiment.pb.go:750\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).processUnaryRPC\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.34.0/server.go:1210\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.34.0/server.go:1533\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1.2\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.34.0/server.go:871\nruntime.goexit\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1357\nFailed
> to authorize with API resource
> references\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/common/util.Wrap\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/common/util/error.go:275\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server.(*ExperimentServer).ListExperiment\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server/experiment_server.go:150\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client._ExperimentService_ListExperiment_Handler.func1\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client/experiment.pb.go:748\nmain.apiServerInterceptor\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/interceptor.go:30\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client._ExperimentService_ListExperiment_Handler\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client/experiment.pb.go:750\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).processUnaryRPC\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.34.0/server.go:1210\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.34.0/server.go:1533\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1.2\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.34.0/server.go:871\nruntime.goexit\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1357","details":[{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/api.Error","error_message":"Internal
> error: Unauthenticated: Request header error: there is no user
> identity header.: Request header error: there is no user identity
> header.\nFailed to authorize with API resource
> references\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/common/util.Wrap\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/common/util/error.go:275\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server.(*ExperimentServer).canAccessExperiment\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server/experiment_server.go:249\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server.(*ExperimentServer).ListExperiment\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server/experiment_server.go:148\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client._ExperimentService_ListExperiment_Handler.func1\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client/experiment.pb.go:748\nmain.apiServerInterceptor\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/interceptor.go:30\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client._ExperimentService_ListExperiment_Handler\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client/experiment.pb.go:750\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).processUnaryRPC\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.34.0/server.go:1210\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.34.0/server.go:1533\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1.2\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.34.0/server.go:871\nruntime.goexit\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1357\nFailed
> to authorize with API resource
> references\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/common/util.Wrap\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/common/util/error.go:275\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server.(*ExperimentServer).ListExperiment\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server/experiment_server.go:150\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client._ExperimentService_ListExperiment_Handler.func1\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client/experiment.pb.go:748\nmain.apiServerInterceptor\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/interceptor.go:30\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client._ExperimentService_ListExperiment_Handler\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client/experiment.pb.go:750\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).processUnaryRPC\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.34.0/server.go:1210\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.34.0/server.go:1533\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1.2\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.34.0/server.go:871\nruntime.goexit\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1357","error_details":"Internal
> error: Unauthenticated: Request header error: there is no user
> identity header.: Request header error: there is no user identity
> header.\nFailed to authorize with API resource
> references\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/common/util.Wrap\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/common/util/error.go:275\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server.(*ExperimentServer).canAccessExperiment\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server/experiment_server.go:249\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server.(*ExperimentServer).ListExperiment\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server/experiment_server.go:148\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client._ExperimentService_ListExperiment_Handler.func1\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client/experiment.pb.go:748\nmain.apiServerInterceptor\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/interceptor.go:30\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client._ExperimentService_ListExperiment_Handler\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client/experiment.pb.go:750\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).processUnaryRPC\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.34.0/server.go:1210\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.34.0/server.go:1533\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1.2\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.34.0/server.go:871\nruntime.goexit\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1357\nFailed
> to authorize with API resource
> references\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/common/util.Wrap\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/common/util/error.go:275\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server.(*ExperimentServer).ListExperiment\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server/experiment_server.go:150\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client._ExperimentService_ListExperiment_Handler.func1\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client/experiment.pb.go:748\nmain.apiServerInterceptor\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/interceptor.go:30\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client._ExperimentService_ListExperiment_Handler\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client/experiment.pb.go:750\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).processUnaryRPC\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.34.0/server.go:1210\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.34.0/server.go:1533\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1.2\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.34.0/server.go:871\nruntime.goexit\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1357"}]}
```

However, listing the pipelines works:

```
import kfp
client = kfp.Client(host='http://localhost:3000')
print(client.list_pipelines())
```

I have verified that the port-forwarding worked - I am able to access the UI at http://localhost:3000/ and can see the pipelines. Any ideas on where I am going wrong with the experiments? The example in the docs seems pretty straightforward but something is not working.

Comment: Did you ever find out the solution?

Comment: @TiDu apologies, I seem to have missed your question. I did - unfortunately this is not supported yet (it is one of the caveats of the multi-user mode). I received feedback from the developers on github and have posted this as the answer. You can track the feature via the #5138 issue included in the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I received feedback from the developers (see the [closed issue](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/issues/6120)). This is one of the current caveats of multi-user mode (see [documentation](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/multi-user/#in-cluster-api-request-authentication)). This usage is now being supported through [#5138](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/issues/5138).

Answer (score 1):

Found [How to do programmatic authentication with Dex? #140](https://github.com/kubeflow/kfctl/issues/140#issuecomment-719894529). By modifying the code as per the solution provided there, it worked.

Need follow the steps at [Connect to Kubeflow Pipelines from outside your cluster](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/sdk/connect-api/#connect-to-kubeflow-pipelines-from-outside-your-cluster) first to be able to connect via localhost:3000.

```
import requests
import kfp
import kfp.dsl as dsl
from kfp.components import create_component_from_func


# Does not work
#import kfp
#client = kfp.Client(host='http://localhost:3000', namespace='kubeflow')
#print(client.list_experiments(namespace='kubeflow'))


# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://github.com/kubeflow/kfctl/issues/140#issuecomment-719894529
# How to do programmatic authentication with Dex? #140
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HOST = "http://localhost:8080/"
USERNAME = "user@example.com"
PASSWORD = "12341234"
NAMESPACE = "kubeflow-user-example-com"

session = requests.Session()
response = session.get(HOST)

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
}

data = {"login": USERNAME, "password": PASSWORD}
session.post(response.url, headers=headers, data=data)
session_cookie = session.cookies.get_dict()["authservice_session"]

client = kfp.Client(
    host=f"{HOST}/pipeline",
    cookies=f"authservice_session={session_cookie}",
    namespace=NAMESPACE,
)

print(client.list_pipelines())


def add(a: float, b: float) -> float:
    '''Calculates sum of two arguments'''
    return a + b


add_op = create_component_from_func(
    add, output_component_file='add_component.yaml')


@dsl.pipeline(
    name='Addition pipeline',
    description='An example pipeline that performs addition calculations.'
)
def add_pipeline(
        a='1',
        b='7',
):
    # Passes a pipeline parameter and a constant value to the `add_op` factory
    # function.
    first_add_task = add_op(a, 4)
    # Passes an output reference from `first_add_task` and a pipeline parameter
    # to the `add_op` factory function. For operations with a single return
    # value, the output reference can be accessed as `task.output` or
    # `task.outputs['output_name']`.
    second_add_task = add_op(first_add_task.output, b)

# Specify argument values for your pipeline run.
arguments = {'a': '7', 'b': '8'}

# Create a pipeline run, using the client you initialized in a prior step.
#client.create_run_from_pipeline_func(add_pipeline, arguments=arguments)

kfp.compiler.Compiler().compile(
    pipeline_func=add_pipeline,
    package_path='pipeline.yaml')
```

Apparently the multi user isolation implementation induced issues, and it seems the documentations under [Pipelines SDK](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/sdk/) have not been updated.