# kubeflow dsl-compile - kfp_server_api.exceptions.ApiException: (400)

Tags: kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

Please help understand what is causing the error and how to resolve.

The [Kubeflow sdk - error in client.list_experiments()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69886126/4281353) refers to [Kubeflow sdk - error in client.list_experiments() #6120](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/issues/6120) github issue through which the author looks fixed the issue.

> I received feedback from the developers (see the [closed issue](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/issues/6120)). This is one of the current caveats of multi-user mode (see [documentation](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/multi-user/#in-cluster-api-request-authentication)). This usage is now being supported through [#5138](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/issues/5138).

However, I could not figure out what is exactly the cause and how to fix it. It looks [Connecting to Kubeflow Pipelines using the SDK client](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/sdk/connect-api/#connect-to-kubeflow-pipelines-from-the-same-cluster) gives the configurations but not sure how exactly I need to do.

## Reproduction steps

1. Deployed Minikube on a remote instance and setup kubectl connection.
2. Deployed Kubeflow 1.5.0 by following [Install with a single command](https://github.com/kubeflow/manifests#install-with-a-single-command).
3. Verify the connection and confirm pods are running from the local laptop.

```
$ kubectl get pods -n kubeflow
NAME                                                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
admission-webhook-deployment-7df7558c67-drdzw                1/1     Running   5          2d18h
cache-deployer-deployment-6f4bcc969-8kpm6                    2/2     Running   15         2d18h
cache-server-575d97c95-k7rv4                                 2/2     Running   10         2d18h
centraldashboard-5dd4f57bbd-gcxn5                            2/2     Running   10         2d18h
jupyter-web-app-deployment-5886974887-8c2cf                  1/1     Running   5          2d18h
katib-controller-58ddb4b856-mzq2l                            1/1     Running   46         2d18h
katib-db-manager-6df878f5b8-c9dhr                            1/1     Running   8          2d18h
katib-mysql-6dcb447c6f-lz5b8                                 1/1     Running   5          2d18h
katib-ui-f787b9d88-8h25n                                     1/1     Running   6          2d18h
kfserving-controller-manager-0                               2/2     Running   50         2d18h
kfserving-models-web-app-7884f597cf-m9n59                    2/2     Running   10         2d18h
kserve-models-web-app-5c64c8d8bb-bpdsb                       2/2     Running   10         2d18h
kubeflow-pipelines-profile-controller-84bcbdb899-669hr       1/1     Running   5          2d18h
metacontroller-0                                             1/1     Running   6          2d18h
metadata-envoy-deployment-7b847ff6c5-d2fjv                   1/1     Running   5          2d18h
metadata-grpc-deployment-6f6f7776c5-2vqp6                    2/2     Running   21         2d18h
metadata-writer-78fc7d5bb8-q8hfq                             2/2     Running   11         2d18h
minio-5b65df66c9-fttpm                                       2/2     Running   10         2d18h
ml-pipeline-75b5c59d7f-k7mm7                                 2/2     Running   59         2d18h
ml-pipeline-persistenceagent-87b6888c4-swv8k                 2/2     Running   10         2d18h
ml-pipeline-scheduledworkflow-665847bb9-4b5vr                2/2     Running   10         2d18h
ml-pipeline-ui-68cc764f66-892rz                              2/2     Running   14         2d18h
ml-pipeline-viewer-crd-68777557fb-6lq88                      2/2     Running   16         2d18h
ml-pipeline-visualizationserver-58ccb76855-qz2rc             2/2     Running   12         2d18h
mysql-f7b9b7dd4-2dpqv                                        2/2     Running   10         2d18h
notebook-controller-deployment-6c5f5d6cfc-mxmzw              2/2     Running   17         2d18h
profiles-deployment-5cdc5dc577-szhjk                         3/3     Running   61         2d18h
tensorboard-controller-controller-manager-5cbddb7fb5-xgq2v   3/3     Running   21         2d18h
tensorboards-web-app-deployment-7c5db448d7-t8xqp             1/1     Running   5          2d18h
training-operator-7b8cc9865d-qr8hm                           1/1     Running   7          2d18h
volumes-web-app-deployment-87484c848-qvsnc                   1/1     Running   5          2d18h
workflow-controller-6bf87db995-snfdn                         2/2     Running   20         2d18h
```

4. Installed kubeflow SDK in the local laptop.

```
$ pip list | grep kfp
kfp                              1.8.12
kfp-pipeline-spec                0.1.15
kfp-server-api                   1.8.1
```

5. Connected to the kubeflow pipeline as per [Connecting to Kubeflow Pipelines using the SDK client](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/sdk/connect-api/)

> kubectl port-forward svc/ml-pipeline-ui 3000:80 --namespace kubeflow\

6. Verified the pipeline ui appears as in the document.

> You can verify that port forwarding is working properly by visiting http://localhost:3000 in your browser. If port forwarding is working properly, the Kubeflow Pipelines UI appears.

[image]

7. Run the code.

```
import kfp
client = kfp.Client(host='http://localhost:3000', namespace='kubeflow')
print(client.list_experiments(namespace='kubeflow'))
```

Got the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "connect_kubeflow_pipeline.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(client.list_experiments(namespace='kubeflow'))
  File "/Users/1245095/venv/ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kfp/_client.py", line 540, in list_experiments
    filter=filter)
  File "/Users/1245095/venv/ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kfp_server_api/api/experiment_service_api.py", line 567, in list_experiment
    return self.list_experiment_with_http_info(**kwargs)  # noqa: E501
  File "/Users/1245095/venv/ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kfp_server_api/api/experiment_service_api.py", line 682, in list_experiment_with_http_info
    collection_formats=collection_formats)
  File "/Users/1245095/venv/ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kfp_server_api/api_client.py", line 369, in call_api
    _preload_content, _request_timeout, _host)
  File "/Users/1245095/venv/ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kfp_server_api/api_client.py", line 188, in __call_api
    raise e
  File "/Users/1245095/venv/ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kfp_server_api/api_client.py", line 185, in __call_api
    _request_timeout=_request_timeout)
  File "/Users/1245095/venv/ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kfp_server_api/api_client.py", line 393, in request
    headers=headers)
  File "/Users/1245095/venv/ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kfp_server_api/rest.py", line 234, in GET
    query_params=query_params)
  File "/Users/1245095/venv/ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kfp_server_api/rest.py", line 224, in request
    raise ApiException(http_resp=r)
kfp_server_api.exceptions.ApiException: (500)
Reason: Internal Server Error
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'X-Powered-By': 'Express', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'date': 'Tue, 24 May 2022 04:58:42 GMT', 'x-envoy-upstream-service-time': '2', 'server': 'envoy', 'connection': 'close', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked'})
HTTP response body: {"error":"Internal error: Unauthenticated: Request header error: there is no user identity header.: Request header error: there is no user identity header.\nFailed to authorize with API resource references\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/common/util.Wrap\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/common/util/error.go:279\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server.(*ExperimentServer).canAccessExperiment\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server/experiment_server.go:249\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server.(*ExperimentServer).ListExperiment\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server/experiment_server.go:148\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client._ExperimentService_ListExperiment_Handler.func1\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client/experiment.pb.go:1089\nmain.apiServerInterceptor\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/interceptor.go:30\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client._ExperimentService_ListExperiment_Handler\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client/experiment.pb.go:1091\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).processUnaryRPC\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.38.0/server.go:1286\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.38.0/server.go:1609\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1.2\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.38.0/server.go:934\nruntime.goexit\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1357\nFailed to authorize with API resource references\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/common/util.Wrap\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/common/util/error.go:279\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server.(*ExperimentServer).ListExperiment\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server/experiment_server.go:150\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client._ExperimentService_ListExperiment_Handler.func1\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client/experiment.pb.go:1089\nmain.apiServerInterceptor\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/interceptor.go:30\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client._ExperimentService_ListExperiment_Handler\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client/experiment.pb.go:1091\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).processUnaryRPC\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.38.0/server.go:1286\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.38.0/server.go:1609\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1.2\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.38.0/server.go:934\nruntime.goexit\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1357","code":13,"message":"Internal error: Unauthenticated: Request header error: there is no user identity header.: Request header error: there is no user identity header.\nFailed to authorize with API resource references\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/common/util.Wrap\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/common/util/error.go:279\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server.(*ExperimentServer).canAccessExperiment\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server/experiment_server.go:249\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server.(*ExperimentServer).ListExperiment\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server/experiment_server.go:148\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client._ExperimentService_ListExperiment_Handler.func1\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client/experiment.pb.go:1089\nmain.apiServerInterceptor\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/interceptor.go:30\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client._ExperimentService_ListExperiment_Handler\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client/experiment.pb.go:1091\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).processUnaryRPC\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.38.0/server.go:1286\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.38.0/server.go:1609\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1.2\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.38.0/server.go:934\nruntime.goexit\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1357\nFailed to authorize with API resource references\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/common/util.Wrap\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/common/util/error.go:279\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server.(*ExperimentServer).ListExperiment\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server/experiment_server.go:150\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client._ExperimentService_ListExperiment_Handler.func1\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client/experiment.pb.go:1089\nmain.apiServerInterceptor\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/interceptor.go:30\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client._ExperimentService_ListExperiment_Handler\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client/experiment.pb.go:1091\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).processUnaryRPC\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.38.0/server.go:1286\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.38.0/server.go:1609\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1.2\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.38.0/server.go:934\nruntime.goexit\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1357","details":[{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/api.Error","error_message":"Internal error: Unauthenticated: Request header error: there is no user identity header.: Request header error: there is no user identity header.\nFailed to authorize with API resource references\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/common/util.Wrap\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/common/util/error.go:279\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server.(*ExperimentServer).canAccessExperiment\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server/experiment_server.go:249\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server.(*ExperimentServer).ListExperiment\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server/experiment_server.go:148\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client._ExperimentService_ListExperiment_Handler.func1\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client/experiment.pb.go:1089\nmain.apiServerInterceptor\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/interceptor.go:30\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client._ExperimentService_ListExperiment_Handler\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client/experiment.pb.go:1091\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).processUnaryRPC\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.38.0/server.go:1286\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.38.0/server.go:1609\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1.2\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.38.0/server.go:934\nruntime.goexit\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1357\nFailed to authorize with API resource references\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/common/util.Wrap\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/common/util/error.go:279\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server.(*ExperimentServer).ListExperiment\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server/experiment_server.go:150\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client._ExperimentService_ListExperiment_Handler.func1\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client/experiment.pb.go:1089\nmain.apiServerInterceptor\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/interceptor.go:30\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client._ExperimentService_ListExperiment_Handler\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client/experiment.pb.go:1091\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).processUnaryRPC\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.38.0/server.go:1286\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.38.0/server.go:1609\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1.2\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.38.0/server.go:934\nruntime.goexit\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1357","error_details":"Internal error: Unauthenticated: Request header error: there is no user identity header.: Request header error: there is no user identity header.\nFailed to authorize with API resource references\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/common/util.Wrap\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/common/util/error.go:279\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server.(*ExperimentServer).canAccessExperiment\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server/experiment_server.go:249\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server.(*ExperimentServer).ListExperiment\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server/experiment_server.go:148\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client._ExperimentService_ListExperiment_Handler.func1\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client/experiment.pb.go:1089\nmain.apiServerInterceptor\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/interceptor.go:30\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client._ExperimentService_ListExperiment_Handler\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client/experiment.pb.go:1091\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).processUnaryRPC\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.38.0/server.go:1286\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.38.0/server.go:1609\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1.2\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.38.0/server.go:934\nruntime.goexit\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1357\nFailed to authorize with API resource references\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/common/util.Wrap\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/common/util/error.go:279\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server.(*ExperimentServer).ListExperiment\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/server/experiment_server.go:150\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client._ExperimentService_ListExperiment_Handler.func1\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client/experiment.pb.go:1089\nmain.apiServerInterceptor\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/src/apiserver/interceptor.go:30\ngithub.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client._ExperimentService_ListExperiment_Handler\n\t/go/src/github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/backend/api/go_client/experiment.pb.go:1091\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).processUnaryRPC\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.38.0/server.go:1286\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.38.0/server.go:1609\ngoogle.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1.2\n\t/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.38.0/server.go:934\nruntime.goexit\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1357"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found [How to do programmatic authentication with Dex? #140](https://github.com/kubeflow/kfctl/issues/140#issuecomment-719894529). By modifying the code as per the solution provided there, it worked.

```
import requests
import kfp
import kfp.dsl as dsl
from kfp.components import create_component_from_func


# Does not work
#import kfp
#client = kfp.Client(host='http://localhost:3000', namespace='kubeflow')
#print(client.list_experiments(namespace='kubeflow'))


# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://github.com/kubeflow/kfctl/issues/140#issuecomment-719894529
# How to do programmatic authentication with Dex? #140
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HOST = "http://localhost:8080/"
USERNAME = "user@example.com"
PASSWORD = "12341234"
NAMESPACE = "kubeflow-user-example-com"

session = requests.Session()
response = session.get(HOST)

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
}

data = {"login": USERNAME, "password": PASSWORD}
session.post(response.url, headers=headers, data=data)
session_cookie = session.cookies.get_dict()["authservice_session"]

client = kfp.Client(
    host=f"{HOST}/pipeline",
    cookies=f"authservice_session={session_cookie}",
    namespace=NAMESPACE,
)

print(client.list_pipelines())


def add(a: float, b: float) -> float:
    '''Calculates sum of two arguments'''
    return a + b


add_op = create_component_from_func(
    add, output_component_file='add_component.yaml')


@dsl.pipeline(
    name='Addition pipeline',
    description='An example pipeline that performs addition calculations.'
)
def add_pipeline(
        a='1',
        b='7',
):
    # Passes a pipeline parameter and a constant value to the `add_op` factory
    # function.
    first_add_task = add_op(a, 4)
    # Passes an output reference from `first_add_task` and a pipeline parameter
    # to the `add_op` factory function. For operations with a single return
    # value, the output reference can be accessed as `task.output` or
    # `task.outputs['output_name']`.
    second_add_task = add_op(first_add_task.output, b)

# Specify argument values for your pipeline run.
arguments = {'a': '7', 'b': '8'}

# Create a pipeline run, using the client you initialized in a prior step.
#client.create_run_from_pipeline_func(add_pipeline, arguments=arguments)

kfp.compiler.Compiler().compile(
    pipeline_func=add_pipeline,
    package_path='pipeline.yaml')
```

Comment: Tried this as well, but failing again at `response = session.get(HOST)` and getting this error `ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7ff0ef408e50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))`

Answer (score 0):

The Kubeflow docs explain how to connect the Kubeflow Pipelines SDK to a dex-authenticated cluster on the ["Connect the Pipelines SDK to Kubeflow Pipelines"](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/v1/sdk/connect-api/) page under the `"Full Kubeflow (from outside cluster)"` heading.

For ease of access, I have included the example code below:

```py
import re
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlsplit

def get_istio_auth_session(url: str, username: str, password: str) -> dict:
    """
    Determine if the specified URL is secured by Dex and try to obtain a session cookie.
    WARNING: only Dex `staticPasswords` and `LDAP` authentication are currently supported
             (we default default to using `staticPasswords` if both are enabled)

    :param url: Kubeflow server URL, including protocol
    :param username: Dex `staticPasswords` or `LDAP` username
    :param password: Dex `staticPasswords` or `LDAP` password
    :return: auth session information
    """
    # define the default return object
    auth_session = {
        "endpoint_url": url,    # KF endpoint URL
        "redirect_url": None,   # KF redirect URL, if applicable
        "dex_login_url": None,  # Dex login URL (for POST of credentials)
        "is_secured": None,     # True if KF endpoint is secured
        "session_cookie": None  # Resulting session cookies in the form "key1=value1; key2=value2"
    }

    # use a persistent session (for cookies)
    with requests.Session() as s:

        ################
        # Determine if Endpoint is Secured
        ################
        resp = s.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
        if resp.status_code != 200:
            raise RuntimeError(
                f"HTTP status code '{resp.status_code}' for GET against: {url}"
            )

        auth_session["redirect_url"] = resp.url

        # if we were NOT redirected, then the endpoint is UNSECURED
        if len(resp.history) == 0:
            auth_session["is_secured"] = False
            return auth_session
        else:
            auth_session["is_secured"] = True

        ################
        # Get Dex Login URL
        ################
        redirect_url_obj = urlsplit(auth_session["redirect_url"])

        # if we are at `/auth?=xxxx` path, we need to select an auth type
        if re.search(r"/auth$", redirect_url_obj.path): 
            
            #######
            # TIP: choose the default auth type by including ONE of the following
            #######
            
            # OPTION 1: set "staticPasswords" as default auth type
            redirect_url_obj = redirect_url_obj._replace(
                path=re.sub(r"/auth$", "/auth/local", redirect_url_obj.path)
            )
            # OPTION 2: set "ldap" as default auth type 
            # redirect_url_obj = redirect_url_obj._replace(
            #     path=re.sub(r"/auth$", "/auth/ldap", redirect_url_obj.path)
            # )
            
        # if we are at `/auth/xxxx/login` path, then no further action is needed (we can use it for login POST)
        if re.search(r"/auth/.*/login$", redirect_url_obj.path):
            auth_session["dex_login_url"] = redirect_url_obj.geturl()

        # else, we need to be redirected to the actual login page
        else:
            # this GET should redirect us to the `/auth/xxxx/login` path
            resp = s.get(redirect_url_obj.geturl(), allow_redirects=True)
            if resp.status_code != 200:
                raise RuntimeError(
                    f"HTTP status code '{resp.status_code}' for GET against: {redirect_url_obj.geturl()}"
                )

            # set the login url
            auth_session["dex_login_url"] = resp.url

        ################
        # Attempt Dex Login
        ################
        resp = s.post(
            auth_session["dex_login_url"],
            data={"login": username, "password": password},
            allow_redirects=True
        )
        if len(resp.history) == 0:
            raise RuntimeError(
                f"Login credentials were probably invalid - "
                f"No redirect after POST to: {auth_session['dex_login_url']}"
            )

        # store the session cookies in a "key1=value1; key2=value2" string
        auth_session["session_cookie"] = "; ".join([f"{c.name}={c.value}" for c in s.cookies])

    return auth_session
```

And then use it with the Kubeflow Pipelines SDK:

```py
import kfp

KUBEFLOW_ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:8080"
KUBEFLOW_USERNAME = "user@example.com"
KUBEFLOW_PASSWORD = "12341234"

auth_session = get_istio_auth_session(
    url=KUBEFLOW_ENDPOINT,
    username=KUBEFLOW_USERNAME,
    password=KUBEFLOW_PASSWORD
)

client = kfp.Client(host=f"{KUBEFLOW_ENDPOINT}/pipeline", cookies=auth_session["session_cookie"])
print(client.list_experiments())
```

The only other thing to note is that you should catch errors when calling methods like `kfp.Client.list_experiments()` if you need to handle the case that your session lasts long enough for your cookie to expire (and run `get_istio_auth_session()` to get a new cookie in that case).